# How can we describe all the maximal normal subgroups of $G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

if $G$ is cyclic of order $n>1$ describe all the maximal normal subgroups of $G$. (We say that $H\trianglelefteq G$ is maximal normal if it doesn't exists $K\trianglelefteq G$ such that $H \nsubseteq  K \nsubseteq  G$)

**My Proof:**
I tried that if $G=\langle a \rangle$ with $|a|=n=P_1^{\alpha_1}P_2^{\alpha_2}...P_p^{\alpha_p}$ and we let be $\langle b_m \rangle \leq \langle a \rangle$ such that $b_m=a^m$ and we observe that $g\langle b_m \rangle=\langle b_m \rangle g$ for all $g\in\langle a \rangle$ then we have that $\langle b_m \rangle \trianglelefteq\langle a \rangle$ and if $x\mid y$ then $\langle b_y \rangle\subseteq\langle b_x \rangle$. Therefore we have that all of the maximal normal subgroups are of the form $\langle b_{p_i} \rangle$ with $i=1, 2, ..., p$

($p$ because we are talking of the primes without power)

But I'm not sure if this is correct

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^ What have you tried? Do you have any ideas? We can help you better once we know where you're getting stuck. Moreover, people tend to dislike questions that look like you want us to do your homework for you, and adding some context will let people know you've thought about the problem yourself

Comment: I've already edited the question, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it! Thinking about the divisibility order on $n$ is the exact right thing to consider. You have also noticed that $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is abelian, so *every* subgroup is normal. This means we're trying to find all the maximal subgroups, since they are automatically normal. That's a great observation.

Then the $\langle a^p \rangle$ for each fixed prime $p | n$ are the maximal normal subgroups! Another way to see that they're maximal is to notice $\frac{|G|}{| \langle a^p \rangle |} = p$ (do you see why?). Do you see why this observation *also* proves that $\langle a^p \rangle$ is maximal?

Again, your proof is perfect! I just don't like leaving answers that say "you did it", so I'm giving another approach too.

---

I hope this helps ^_^